# How to specify python version on self-hosted (Linux Ubuntu 18.04) agent while running a pipeline through MS DevOps

Tags: python, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to run a simple bash script using a yaml pipeline through MS DevOps. I want to be using Python version 3.8. When connecting to the self-hosted agent via SSH, I am able to run the script specified in the yaml file without any problems. However, when I run the script through the pipeline, it fails because for some reason the `python` alias is referring to Python 2.7.17.

I tried setting the following alias in both the `.bashrc` for the `agentsvc` user as well as in the `bash.bashrc` file: `alias python='python3.8'`.

I realize I can change `python` to `python3.8` in my script however I do not want to do this. Does anybody have any ideas why the alias is not working in the pipeline environment and what I can do to fix this?

Here is a sample of the yaml pipeline that I am trying to run:

```
pool: myubuntuagent

trigger:
  - master

steps:
  - script: |
      # install pre-requisites
      whoami
      python -V
      python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    displayName: 'Install Prerequisites etc. etc. etc.'
```

Comment: The Python executable is normally a symbolic link to a given version of Python and so you can probably just change the link accordingly i.e. /usr/bin/python may link to /usr/bin/python2 for example.

Comment: thanks @RamanSailopal, I looked into this option but it seems like this might cause some issues with the system as noted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351318/changing-symlink-python-to-python3-causes-problems). What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, we can try below cmd to use Python3.x version

```
python3 -V
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Result:

[image]

Also, we can use the task `Use Python version` to specify python version.  You can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version?view=azure-devops#how-can-i-configure-a-self-hosted-agent-to-use-this-task) to configure your self-hosted agent to use this task.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @vito, thanks for the reply. The python3 alias is current pointing to python3.6 on our VM. I looked into using the Use Python Version task but this seemed really complicated for achieving something seemingly simple. When we were using the public agent, this task worked well but the custom configuration on a linux VM does not seem straight forward.

Comment: Hi @davjfish, you could try it with the task Use Python Version, if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Comment: Hi @davjfish, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi @vito, Thanks for checking in. When I had read through the docs originally, the process of adding the Python version to the tool cache on the self-hosted agent seemed a bit too complicated for my blood. If I understand correctly, it means installing the desired version of python from a zip file into the `AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY`. This is something I have no experience with and do not have the time to explore. Instead, I opted for simply specifying the python binary to use in my yaml scripts (i.e. calling `python3.8 ...`) despite this not being the optimal solution.

Comment: Hi @davjfish, If you are using self-hosted agent, and the system environment has been configured, all python version could be used directly without additional configuration in the Azure DevOps pipeline. In addition, do you mind adding your workaround as answer and accept it? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: Hi @vito, thanks again for the reply. Since my original question was about not having to specify the version of python in the script, I would not want to post my workaround as a solution since that was precisely what I ended up doing.

Comment: You should add python3.8 to self-hosted agent _tool folder and then use the task Use Python version to specify python version. By the way, If the answer is helpful for you, do you mind Accepting it? it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: thanks for your post . you save me @Vito-Liu